# Why is Akka creating so many dispatchers?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using Akka for several different Actors. The work done by these Actors is non-blocking. I noticed something odd - the number of dispatchers scales with the number of Actors I'm creating. If I create hundreds of actors, I find myself with hundreds of dispatchers, sometimes over 1000.

This is, even though, most of the dispatchers look like this:

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000003d503de50> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

(basically, doing nothing most of the time)

I initialize dispatchers with calls like this:

```
ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(system).withDispatcher(s"akka.dispatchers.$dispatcherName"))(system))
```

My dispatcher configuration is below (we have different dispatchers for different actors):

```
    dispatchers {

      connector-actor-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          fixed-pool-size = 200
        }
        throughput = 1
      }

      http-actor-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "fork-join-executor"
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 1
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 64
          task-peeking-mode = "FIFO"
        }
        throughput = 1
      }

      commands-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "fork-join-executor"
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 1
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 64
          task-peeking-mode = "FIFO"
        }
        throughput = 1
      }

      http-server-dispatcher {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          core-pool-size-factor = 1
        }
        throughput = 1
      }

      http-client-dispatcher-low {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          core-pool-size-factor = 1
        }
        throughput = 1
      }

      http-client-dispatcher-high {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          core-pool-size-factor = 1
        }
        throughput = 1
      }

      http-client-dispatcher-parser {
        type = Dispatcher
        executor = "thread-pool-executor"
        thread-pool-executor {
          fixed-pool-size = 200
        }
        throughput = 1
      }
    }
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you explain why you need different dispatchers for each actor? Typically there is a single dispatcher for the whole system. If you are creating hundreds of actors and each actor has its own dispatcher with many threads, you are going to get a lot of threads!

Comment: Sounds like OP gets misinformed that each actor _needs_ a separate Dispatcher. Maybe they think it is required to make them "non-blocking".

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok you are correct, that was the thinking. So why would someone need separate dispatchers in an actorsystem?

Comment: One example that comes to mind: maybe some actors would be performing IO work with blocking operations (which blocks the thread that the actor run on), and it would be nice to not block other actors who don't have to wait for their response idly, because with enough actors doing blocking things dispatcher would run out of threads. (You could use `scala.concurrent.blocking` but it isn't always good).

Comment: But in general having 2, rarely 3 thread pools in enough.

Comment: And arguably actors doing background work should probably use a task model of some sort rather than futures or blocking message handling.

Comment: Why @Tim? Why switch them?

Comment: As @MateuszKubuszok says there are issues with blocking `Futures` so it can be better to use more of a thread model where an explicit thread/task does the IO and communicates with the Actor when interesting data is received or consumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this mostly answered in the comments above, but to collate them into an "Answer": it appears that "so many dispatchers" are getting created because you are creating them explicitly in your config.

Also, when you give an example of a "dispatcher" you are actually showing a thread stack trace. So you might be confusing threads with dispatchers. And many of the the dispatchers you are creating have large thread counts. As @Tim says "If you are creating hundreds of actors and each actor has its own dispatcher with many threads, you are going to get a lot of threads!"

But that's really a tuning question. The answer to the direct question is that generally (with the exception of the system dispatcher), dispatchers are generally only created when you specifically ask for them to be created. And it appears that you are creating many of them. And that you also have enormous thread counts for each dispatcher.

As discussed, the general best practice is to have one dispatcher for non-blocking actors and another dispatcher with blocking actors. Each dispatcher will also generally only need a small number of threads. There are some edge cases where you might want additional dedicated dispatchers for particularly sensitive or badly behaving actors, but it depends on your actors and your application.